# Make a dictionary from parsed data python

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

I have this code right here that parses som information from the web:

```
import lxml.html
from lxml.etree import XPath
import json



url = "http://gbgfotboll.se/information/?scr=table&ftid=51168"
date = '2014-09-27'
# use this in real mode: currentDate = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
list = []
id = 0
score = ""
rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table[3]/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))
time_xpath = XPath("td[1]/span/span//text()[2]")
team_xpath = XPath("td[2]/a/text()")

html = lxml.html.parse(url)

for row in rows_xpath(html):
    time = time_xpath(row)[0].strip()
    team = team_xpath(row)[0]
    list.append("%d:"%id  + time + " " + team + " " + score)
    id += 1

print json.dumps(list)
```

which prints:

```
0:13:00 Romelanda UF - IK Virgo (empty score for now)
1:15:00 Kode IF - IK Kongah\xe4lla (empty score)
etc..
```

My first sub question is that some of the parsed data will contain the letters "å" "ä" "ö" how would i fix so it prints out the correct letters as you see in the result(second row) it prints out "Kongah\xe4lla" which should be "Konghälla"

Main question how would i turn that list to a dictionary so that the final json output would be like:

```
{"id":"0", "time":"13:00", "teams":"Romelanda UF - IK Virgo", "score":"empty" }
etc...
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, \xe4 is not a ascii char, if you want to print it out, may be you can try to decode it with some encoding witch seems to be "windows-1252".

when i try this, it worked for me:

```
a='\xe4'
b=a.decode('windows-1252')
print b
```

For your second question, just modify the code to this:

```
for i,row in enumerate(rows_xpath(html)):
    #
    #
    list.append({"id":str(i), "time":time, "teams":team, "score":score})
```

and I think you don't really want to name your list "list", it's kind of the keyword of python ~ 
good luck.

by the way, the enumerate generates the index automatically, you can still use your "id" instead, just with this :

```
 list.append({"id":str(id), "time":time, "teams":team, "score":score})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot. But regarding your first answer. As you can see its parsing the information from the web so i don't know which of the three letters will occur when and where. There will be new information parsed everyday so how would i make something that would check every time time it parses and corrects it? @lisnb

also please do note that you cannot use .append when it comes to dictionaries.